# Is a Youtube buffer finish event possible

Tags: javascript, youtube, buffering

Is it possible to detect the finish of a youtube buffering through javascript? Here http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html are a lot of methods but no one has an event that says "finished with buffering".

Answer (score 0):

```
var ytplayer;

function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    checkBuffer();
}

function checkBuffer(){
    if(ytplayer.getVideoBytesLoaded() == ytplayer.getVideoBytesTotal()){
        alert('Buffer Complete!');
    }else{
        var t = setTimeout(function(){
            Editor.split();
        },1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works when the entire video has completed buffering. I think Bartosz meant how to check if the video had buffered enough for the player to start playing.

Comment: Exactly. He asked for "finish of a youtube buffering". If you need to start something before that just change the "ytplayer.getVideoBytesLoaded() == ytplayer.getVideoBytesTotal()" logic to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but the answer may still be helpful to some:

The YouTube video can be in one of 6 states:

- -1 – unstarted
- 0 – ended
- 1 – playing
- 2 – paused
- 3 – buffering
- 5 – video cued

When this state changes (i.e. when the video stops buffering and enters a 'paused' or a 'played' state), the "onStateChange" event is triggered. So, keep track of the previous state and the new state. When the previous state is 'buffering' and the new state is 'ended', 'playing', or 'paused', then this means that the video finished buffering.

Here is an example:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="player"></div>
  <script>
    var player;
    var lastState;

    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }


    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (lastState == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING &&
            (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING || event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED)) {
            alert('Buffering has completed!');
        }
        lastState = event.data;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```